# Empty where clauses in mysql (while I am using RMySql dbGetQuery)

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rmysql

I want to do something really similar to these:

[When mysql WHERE clause is empty, return all rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045351/when-mysql-where-clause-is-empty-return-all-rows)

[Possible to have PHP MYSQL query ignore empty variable in WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339587/possible-to-have-php-mysql-query-ignore-empty-variable-in-where-clause)

I want the where clause to be ignored if the variable I am subsetting by is `NULL`. However, I am accessing my MySQL database from R using dbGetQuery. So far, I have code like this

```
write_pid_clause = function(p_id=NULL){
 if(is.null(p_id)){return(NULL)}
 else {return(paste0("where project_id = ",p_id)  )}
}
```

which writes the correct `where` statement behaviour if `p_id` is not specified, together with the code:

```
  dbGetQuery( con,paste0("select MIN(completion_date) from run ",write_pid_clause(p_id))))
```

This works properly, however, I struggle if I wish to insert more conditions in the where clause, e.g. if I wanted to add the condition `and status = 'complete'` when `p_id = NULL`.

Does anyone have any good ideas on how I can elegantly do this in R?

**EDIT**
Here is some more code to demonstrate what I am trying to do, this is with respect to `and` clauses after a join (doing the `where` is a little bit trickier)

```
make_and_clauses = function(p_id = "",start_date="", end_date=""){

 conditions = list(
   list(" and r.project_id ='", p_id,"'"),
   list(" and r.completion_date >= '",start_date,"'"),
   list(" and r.completion_date <= '", end_date, "'"))
 condition_values = c(p_id,start_date, end_date)
 conditions[which(condition_values =="")] <- ""
 conditions = unlist(conditions,recursive=TRUE)
 paste0(conditions,collapse="")

}
```

which gives output

```
> make_and_clauses(2,3,4)
[1] " and r.project_id ='2' and r.completion_date >= '3' and r.completion_date <= '4'"
> make_and_clauses(2,,4)
[1] " and r.project_id ='2' and r.completion_date <= '4'"
> make_and_clauses(,3,2)
[1] " and r.completion_date >= '3' and r.completion_date <= '2'"

>
```

Comment: I don't think there is an easy/simple/clear way to achieve what you want. If you want to be able to add multiple clauses, each dependent upon the contents of a variable, you have to build up each one. The only relevant SQL trick I can think of is to put `WHERE 1=1 ` in the SQL statement, then add `AND column = value` for each value. This way, if you leave one out, the syntax is still correct.

Comment: Hi, that actually sounds really good. See the new code I have written to handle multiple missing cases. In that case the `Where 1 = 1` command is exactly what I need to handle the case where I have to use `where`. If you post it as an answer I'l upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your function I proposed something like:

```r
make_and_clauses <- function(p_id, start_date, end_date) {
    conditions = c(
        if (!missing(p_id)) sprintf("r.project_id ='%i'", p_id),
        if (!missing(start_date)) sprintf("r.completion_date >= '%i'", start_date),
        if (!missing(end_date)) sprintf("r.completion_date <= '%i'", end_date)
    )
    paste(conditions, collapse=" and ")
}
```

which returns:

```r
make_and_clauses(2,3,4)
# [1] "r.project_id ='2' and r.completion_date >= '3' and r.completion_date <= '4'"
make_and_clauses(2,,4)
# [1] "r.project_id ='2' and r.completion_date <= '4'"
make_and_clauses(,3,2)
# [1] "r.completion_date >= '3' and r.completion_date <= '2'"
make_and_clauses(,3,)
# [1] "r.completion_date >= '3'"
```

What important that no arguments at all leads to:

```r
make_and_clauses(,,)
# [1] ""
```

So it's possible to write `WHERE` clause:

```r
make_and_clauses <- function(p_id, start_date, end_date) {
    conditions = c(
        if (!missing(p_id)) sprintf("r.project_id ='%i'", p_id),
        if (!missing(start_date)) sprintf("r.completion_date >= '%i'", start_date),
        if (!missing(end_date)) sprintf("r.completion_date <= '%i'", end_date)
    )
    if (length(conditions)>0) paste("WHERE", paste(conditions, collapse=" and ")) else ""
}
```

and use it as

```r
paste("select MIN(completion_date) from run", make_and_clauses(,3,2))
# [1] "select MIN(completion_date) from run WHERE r.completion_date >= '3' and r.completion_date <= '2'"
paste("select MIN(completion_date) from run", make_and_clauses())
# [1] "select MIN(completion_date) from run "
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed, without resorting to `where 1 = 1`. I particularly like the usage of `!missing` and `sprintf`. Now to convert the first batch of code to something which can handle an arbitrary list of arguments.

Comment: something like `lapply( as.list(args(make_and_clauses), function(arg) {if(!missing(arg)) sprintf(arg, eval(arg)})`...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy/simple/clear way to achieve what you want. If you want to be able to add multiple clauses, each dependent upon the contents of a variable, you have to build up each one. The only relevant SQL trick I can think of is to put `WHERE 1=1` in the SQL statement, then add `AND column = value` for each value. This way, if you leave one out, the syntax is still correct.

I see that @Marek has provided an answer with code; perhaps you can combine the answers to produce a workable solution.

Comment: `status` could be null as well. Also, the where clause may contain more than 2 conditional checks, and it becomes impractical to write all the possible if clauses.